# Vim in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: github, vim, windows-10, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
# You may need the following to create the directoy
$ mkdir -p $(jupyter --data-dir)/nbextensions
# Now clone the repository
$ cd $(jupyter --data-dir)/nbextensions
$ git clone https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding vim_binding
$ chmod -R go-w vim_binding
```

I found [this](https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding/wiki/Installation) installation guide to include vim in Jupyter. But I don't understand the above installation step.

I am using Windows 10 and Chrome. Where should I run those code? Anaconda prompt or cmd?

Comment: Instructions say: *from a shell (e.g. bash)*. You can try `git-bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Those are instructions for a linux environment. You can use either cygwin or the Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL).